# Create a slider with columns using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site with 4 columns.
I would like to make it responsive but instead of displaying the columns at the bottom like Bootstrap's default method, I would like columns to be full width of the device and slide between them.

Here is a schema:

[image: schema]

And what I did so far:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qx4Eu/1/embedded/result/)

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
.container {
    max-width: none !important;
}
.column1 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

}

Is it possible to make a column full width using device width and not container width?
Do I have to use javascript?

Comment: Display table comes to mind, but you're going to have to use javascript for the swipes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using javascript, you can use [Swipe.js](http://swipejs.com/)

The html structure goes like so:

```
<div id='slider' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.swipe {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

And the Javascript looks like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.mySwipe = Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
}
```

Don't forget to include the javascript file:
https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/blob/master/swipe.js

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/FjvEb/1/)

**Edit** Providing you only want this to apply to mobile devices, here's the mobile specific code:

The HTML would change to this:

```
<div id='slider'>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript would change to this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if ( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    if (slider.classList) {
      slider.classList.add('swipe');
      slider.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].classList.add('swipe-wrap');
    } else {
      slider.className += 'swipe';
      slider.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].className += 'swipe-wrap';
    }
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
  }
}
```

Here's another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/FjvEb/4/)

Comment: That works really great, thank you! I'll have to find out how to enable this for mobile devices only though.

Comment: @Vilarix I've updated my answer. You can add your own classes to the code to style it, just avoid making changes to the `swipe` and `swipe-wrap` classes. Also don't forget you still need the CSS in the mobile version.